# Write data linked at button to database

Tags: php, html

I want to write different type of data linked at buttons to my database.

**My code:**

```
if (isset($_POST['toevoegen']))
{
    $query = "select * from `product`";

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Er is een fout opgetreden bij het uitvoeren van de query: \"$query\"");

    $i=1;

    while($rij = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        if ($rij['ID'] == $_POST[$i])
        {
            $product = $rij['ID'];
            $prijs = $rij['Prijs'];


            $query2 = "insert into `bestelling` (`ProductID`,`Prijs`) values ('$product', '$prijs')";
            mysqli_query($link, $query2) or die("Er is een fout opgetreden bij het uitvoeren van de query: \"$query\"");
        }

        $i++;
    }
}
```

....

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM product";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Er is een fout opgetreden bij het uitvoeren van de query: \"$query\"");

$i=0;

echo("<table id=\"product\">");
echo("<tr>");

while($rij = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $i++;
    $afbeelding = $rij['Img'];
    echo("
            <td><img src=$afbeelding>
            <p>&euro;".$rij['Prijs']."</p>
            <p>".$rij['Naam']."</p>
            <p><form action='' method='POST'>
                <input class= 'nummers' type='number' name=".$rij['ID']." min='1' max='20'>
                <input type='submit' value='In mandje' name= 'toevoegen'>
            </form></p></td>");
    if ($i==3) 
    {
        echo("</tr>");
        echo("<tr>");
        $i=0;
    }

}
echo("</table>");


mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
```

**I'm getting al these errors:**

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\Users\vincent\Documents\XAMPP\htdocs\PHP\Project\Home.php on line 65

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\Users\vincent\Documents\XAMPP\htdocs\PHP\Project\Home.php on line 65

Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in C:\Users\vincent\Documents\XAMPP\htdocs\PHP\Project\Home.php on line 65

Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in C:\Users\vincent\Documents\XAMPP\htdocs\PHP\Project\Home.php on line 65

Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in C:\Users\vincent\Documents\XAMPP\htdocs\PHP\Project\Home.php on line 65

Notice: Undefined offset: 7 in C:\Users\vincent\Documents\XAMPP\htdocs\PHP\Project\Home.php on line 65

Notice: Undefined offset: 8 in C:\Users\vincent\Documents\XAMPP\htdocs\PHP\Project\Home.php on line 65

Notice: Undefined offset: 9 in C:\Users\vincent\Documents\XAMPP\htdocs\PHP\Project\Home.php on line 65

Notice: Undefined offset: 10 in C:\Users\vincent\Documents\XAMPP\htdocs\PHP\Project\Home.php on line 65

Notice: Undefined offset: 11 in C:\Users\vincent\Documents\XAMPP\htdocs\PHP\Project\Home.php on line 65

Notice: Undefined offset: 12 in C:\Users\vincent\Documents\XAMPP\htdocs\PHP\Project\Home.php on line 65

Notice: Undefined offset: 13 in C:\Users\vincent\Documents\XAMPP\htdocs\PHP\Project\Home.php on line 65

Notice: Undefined offset: 14 in C:\Users\vincent\Documents\XAMPP\htdocs\PHP\Project\Home.php on line 65

Notice: Undefined offset: 15 in C:\Users\vincent\Documents\XAMPP\htdocs\PHP\Project\Home.php on line 65

Notice: Undefined offset: 16 in C:\Users\vincent\Documents\XAMPP\htdocs\PHP\Project\Home.php on line 65

Notice: Undefined offset: 17 in C:\Users\vincent\Documents\XAMPP\htdocs\PHP\Project\Home.php on line 65

Notice: Undefined offset: 18 in C:\Users\vincent\Documents\XAMPP\htdocs\PHP\Project\Home.php on line 65
```

Comment: Take a look at line 65. You're getting errors because the array does not contain the offset that you are trying to obtain.

Comment: The PHP interpreter is telling you exactly **what** the error is and even **where** it is ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the contents of line 65 is, but taking a guess it's this:

```
if ($rij['ID'] == $_POST[$i])
```

The error is saying that `$_POST[$i]` doesn't exist - there is no value in the array at offset `$i`.

---

If you want to compare even if `$_POST[$i]` is invalid, you can use the [at sign error control operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php), which suppresses errors:

```
if($rij['ID'] == @$_POST[$i])
```

Comment: Is there an other way to compare the numbers without getting al these errors?

Comment: See my edit - added info about the "at sign error control operator".